# Spring Batch - Erro Config XML job - Date

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch

I have a procedure in sql waiting three parameters. The first 2 parameters are dates and last a cursor.

How do I configure the XML job Spring Batch

I tried so

```
<bean id="databaseItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="procedureName" value="MyProcedureSQL" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="50" />        
        <property name="parameters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">                   
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_INICIO"/>
                    <constructor-arg index="1">
                        <util:constant static-field="java.sql.TYPES.Date"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">                   
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_TERMINO"/>
                    <constructor-arg index="1">
                        <util:constant static-field="java.sql.TYPES.Date"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>             

                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">                   
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_RESULT"/>
                    <constructor-arg index="1">
                        <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.int"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="main.java.br.com.util.DataEmployeeMapper" />
        </property>
        <property name="refCursorPosition" value="3"/>
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="preparedStatementSetter" />
    </bean>
```

It appears the error

**Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Date**

In this variation I have also tried

```
<util:constant static-field="java.sql.Date"/>
<util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.timeStamp"/>
```

How do I set to send the two dates for procedure?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace not only one line

Comment: take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html it should be e.g. java.sql.Types.INTEGER

Answer (score 0):

It may help to change use argument names instead of 'index' in the constructor-arg element, to debug this. e.g. change

```
<constructor-arg index="1">
   <util:constant static-field="java.sql.TYPES.Date"/>
</constructor-arg>
```

to this

```
<constructor-arg name="sqlType">
   <util:constant static-field="java.sql.TYPES.Date"/>
</constructor-arg>
```

I suspect you there may be some ambiguity around what constructor is called and how the argument types are interpreted